# Passing js array as a parameter to dynamically created table row's onclick event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I create a table dynamically and i want to pass js array to row;

```js
var html= "<table id='tableID'><thead>...</thead><tbody></tbody></table>";
var jsArray = [{id: 1, val: "test"},{id: 2, val: "test2"}];
    
html+= '<tr onclick="myFunction('+jsArray+')"></tr>'
    

$('#tableID tbody').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I tried `JSON.stringify(jsArray)` then pass it but it doesn't work. Maybe I can change " with " but it doesn't looks best practice.

Comment: Seems confusing. You are adding row after the table body. and also passing `jsArray` to myfunction.

Comment: sorry, i didn't write all html string to here, editted now.

Comment: Still same question. Do you want to add row after the closing of table. if that so, this is wrong html semantic

Comment: yes, i append tr to table, there is no problem about it, my question is about passing array object to function dynamically.

Comment: You have a syntax issue on the first line so this will never work/run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason JSON.stringify(jsArray) doesn't work is because the result includes double quotes, and as the value of the onclick attribute, it is put inside double quotes already.  So, it should work if you use single quotes. Try changing `onclick="..."` to `onclick='...'`